# What happens when I install the package "linux"?

Tags: 10.04, kernel

I see a package called "Linux" in Synaptic in 10.04, and I want to know what happens when I install it, without making my system unusable. Does it make a dual-boot option (I have only Ubuntu), or replace my kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very little - as per this [link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/linux) -

This will install whatever is the latest kernel for your distribution.

Perhaps only useful if you accidentally delete your latest kernel and you want a quick way to install the latest available.

Comment: I sure I hope I don't delete my kernel!

Answer (score 0):

If you install this package nothing will change. The package `linux` is a meta package which depends on the latest Linux kernel. So if you don't have installed the latest one it will install it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I might try it to see if I have the latest.